# Return false doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i think my `return false` code isnt working properly. Take a look:

```
 $(".home .options .tabs ul li a").click(function(e){



    var qual = $(this).attr("href");

    $(".content.home .options .tabs ul li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");

    $(".content.home .options .holder .tab").hide();
    $(".content.home .options .holder "+qual).show();

    return false;


});
```

Here's my html code:

```
 <div class="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#lancamentos">Lançamentos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#obras">Em Obras</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#prontos">Prontos para Morar</a></li>
                </ul>
  </div><!-- tabs -->
```

When i click, it does not go to the link, but jumps the page. Whats happening?

thanks!

**UPDATE**

Ok, i have updated the code. And still not working.

Comment: That might help : http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: @David Laberge: I think it's rather about `preventDefault` to stop the navigation.

Comment: Jumps the page ? What are actually trying to say?

Answer (score 6):

You need to cancel the click on the `<a>` tag, not the containing `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrote `return false` in click event of your `li` you should write it for `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You don't require to return true/false. OnClick functionality of anchor should work here. I tested below code. You can use firebug to debug the code.

```
$(".tabs ul li").click(function(e){
   var qual = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
   $(".tabs ul li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```